# BIP67 + importmulti + multisig descriptors

Tags: json-rpc, multi-signature

I'm trying to setup a Bitcoin Core watch-only wallet using `importmulti` and a `sh(multi(m,xpub1/*,...,xpubn/*))` ranged descriptor, and then use `deriveaddresses` to get receiving addresses.

Is it possible to import only BIP-67-compliant addresses somehow? With a ranged descriptor I can't manually order the multisig script pubkeys from my side as suggested in [this abandoned PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/8751#issuecomment-308748042) because my client only touches the account xpubs.

I could manually inspect and skip addresses until I get ordered pubkeys, but that's really ugly and fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the descriptors language currently doesn't support BIP67.

It would be easy to add a multi_bip67 or so to the language if there is a need for it.

Comment: There's a PR for that now: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/17056